# How to connect PostgreSQL database to log analytics workspace in azure via powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

I have created postgreSql db in azure. Also I have created log analytics workspace in azure under same subscription. How can I connect my PostgresSql DB to log analytics workspace.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps will be helpful for you to integrate log analytics workspace with Azure postgres.

1. In the Azure portal go to Postgres
2. Select Diagnostic Settings in the menu of your Postgres
3. Click Add diagnostic setting
4. Enter Name
5. Select `send to log analytics` in the destination details
6. Select your preferred subscription and log analytics workspace
7. Select the log type PostgreSQLLogs
8. Save your setting

Comment: These are all manual steps.
As I have already mentioned in the question that I need this via powershell